# Overlaying a view does not disable actions on underlying view

Tags: android, view, overlay, android-view, android-overlay

I have 2 views : View A and view B. View A is rendered and has actions to input a text value. Im displaying an overlay view - View B on top of this. I expect that the actions on View A get disabled but they do not and im still able to type in the input field on View A. How can i disable this ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason is that your overlay is not consuming the touch events , so by design if a view is not consuming touch events the events are passed to underlying view in the view model. So the long answer is make your overlay touchable, focusable , and touch listener and return true . short answer is add `android:clickable="true"` to your overlay view.